# validate all cousin input element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to query. Each row has multiple input element including submit image button. I want to disable save button while typing if there is any empty input value in that row. I succeed wring following code. Is this correct way? Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance

```
$(':text').bind('input propertychange', function()  {

    var valid = true;
    var $this=$(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':text');

    $this.each(function() { 
        if(!$(this).val()) {
            valid = false;
        }
    });

    if(!valid)
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').attr('src', 'image/savedisabled.png');
        $(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').attr('src', 'image/save.png')
        $(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').prop('disabled', false);
    }

});
<table>
<tbody> 
        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="1" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Test 1" size="50"/></td>          
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415" size="10"/></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1" checked></td>                    
           <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/savedisabled.png" height="13" alt="Submit"></td>
         </tr>
        </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="2" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Test 2" size="50" /></td>         
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415" size="10" /></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"  ></td>                    
           <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/save.png" height="13" alt="Submit" ></td>
         </tr>
         </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="3" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Test 3" size="50" /></td>         
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415" size="10" /></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"  ></td>                    
           <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/save.png" height="13" alt="Submit" ></td>
         </tr>
         </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="4" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" size="50"/></td>          
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415"  size="10"/></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"></td>                    
           <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/savedisabled.png" height="13"  alt="Submit"></td>
         </tr>
         </form>                      
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the parents('form'), but it looks like you're trying to find siblings? There is also a siblings() function: 
   `$(this).siblings();` You can pass in a selector to a function to further narrow elements, like with `$(this).siblings('input:text');` or `$(this).parents('form');`
2. Secondly use on() instead of bind(), bind() is the old way of doing it. Also on() works on dynamically inserted elements.
3. Don't need to use prop(), can use attr() too, you can also attach that to the end of the first jquery statement. Meaning:

`$(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').attr('src', 'image/savedisabled.png').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

or even more succinct:

`$(this).parent().parent().children('td').children(':image').attr({ src:"image/savedisabled.png", disabled:"disabled" });`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I do for the same for other element checkbox and select option $(':text', ':checkbox','select' ).on('???', function() {}

Comment: You can use on keyup for text inputs and on change for select and checkbox. Also there should only be one selector parameter to on, meaning $(' :checkbox, select').on('change', function({...}));

Answer (score 0):

I figured to give your form a little try as well. I got it to work pretty well ^^. I gave the button a color to indicate if it is active or not. I also took the liberty to change some other properties (you can change this to your own preferences). I assumed the relevant textboxes would all be empty when loading the page and set them all to disable the button.

It should be easy to change the conditions of each textbox in this code. It should also be self-explanatory thow to add more textboxes to check.

Read the comments in the code/JSFiddle for more explanation. If you have more questions just ask ^^.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tbody> 
        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="1" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Test 1" size="50"/></td>          
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415" size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"/></td>                    
            <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/savedisabled.png" height="13" alt="Submit"/></td>
         </tr>
        </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="2" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="50" /></td>         
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="1415" size="10" /></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"  ></td>                    
           <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/save.png" height="13" alt="Submit" ></td>
         </tr>
         </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="3" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" value="Test 3" size="50" /></td>         
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="10" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"  /></td>                    
               <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/save.png" height="13" alt="Submit" /></td>
         </tr>
         </form>

        <form action="" method="post">   
        <tr>                   
           <td><input type="text" name="id" value="4" size="4"/></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="name" size="50"/></td>          
           <td><input type="text" name="year" value=""  size="10"/></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="readonly" value="1"/></td>                    
            <td><input type="image" name="save_submit" src="image/savedisabled.png" height="13"  alt="Submit"/></td>
         </tr>
         </form>                      
</tbody>
</table>
```

**JQuery (It is easier to read the JSFiddle)**

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("input[name='save_submit']")
            .css({'background-color': 'red', 'cursor': 'default'})/*Just for visualising that all buttons are disabled. Change to your personal taste*/
            .attr('disabled', true);/*disabling all submitbuttons*/
        $(':text').on('keyup'/*Using keyup so the event triggers after typing something*/, function(){                       
            var ValueName = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td').children('input[name="name"]').val();/*Get the value of the appropriate "name"-input*/
            var ValueYear = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td').children('input[name="year"]').val();/*Get the value of the appropriate "year"-input*/
            if(ValueName !== "" && ValueYear !== "") /*check  if all variables have content*/{$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td').children('input[name="save_submit"]').css({'background-color': 'green', 'cursor': 'pointer'}).attr('disabled', false);}/*Change submit button properties if all the input-items contain information*/
            else{$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td').children('input[name="save_submit"]').css({'background-color': 'red', 'cursor': 'default'}).attr('disabled', true); }/*Change submit button properties if NOT all the input-items contain information*/
        }); //End keyup
    }); // End ready
```

[**JSFiddle (read comments and try it out)**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0rd0k64/)